# Setting up django-nonrel?

Tags: python, django, nosql, django-nonrel

I'm trying to set up [django-nonrel](http://django-mongodb.org/topics/setup.html) into a new virtualenv, but am getting an error saying: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

I can't tell from the error log exactly which file or directory is missing. Please could anyone suggest what might be going wrong?

The bitbucket file seems to be present:

```
(nonrel)delirium:nonrel anna$ pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/django-nonrel
Downloading/unpacking hg+https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/django-nonrel
  Cloning hg https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/django-nonrel to /var/folders/q5/_0_8qh59147_0vmr8tm1_mq80000gn/T/pip-3Trv56-build
  Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory while executing command /usr/local/bin/hg clone --noupdate -q https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/django-nonrel /var/folders/q5/_0_8qh59147_0vmr8tm1_mq80000gn/T/pip-3Trv56-build
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anna/Dropbox/nonrel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/anna/Dropbox/nonrel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 245, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Users/anna/Dropbox/nonrel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 985, in prepare_files
    self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)
  File "/Users/anna/Dropbox/nonrel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1103, in unpack_url
    return unpack_vcs_link(link, loc, only_download)
  File "/Users/anna/Dropbox/nonrel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 294, in unpack_vcs_link
    vcs_backend.unpack(location)
  File "/Users/anna/Dropbox/nonrel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/__init__.py", line 233, in unpack
    self.obtain(location)
  File "/Users/anna/Dropbox/nonrel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 81, in obtain
    call_subprocess([self.cmd, 'clone', '--noupdate', '-q', url, dest])
  File "/Users/anna/Dropbox/nonrel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 221, in call_subprocess
    cwd=cwd, env=env)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Storing complete log in /Users/anna/.pip/pip.log
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend getting the latest version from github

https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel

You'd wanna use git to download it rather than pip.